# CakePHP + lightbox2 (dont show photo - blank photo)

Tags: cakephp, lightbox2

Does anybody have any ideas why lightbox2 is working like that:
When I click on the photo it looking like it is working, it adds the background but inside is only white square and nothing more - there aren't buttons and it even does not try to show picture (like this:
[lightbox http://img228.imageshack.us/img228/2608/10505916.th.png](http://img228.imageshack.us/img228/2608/10505916.th.png)

When I check source code it see all my js files. But it looks like one of them does not want to work (I think this: echo $javascript->link('scriptaculous.js');) I tried: echo $javascript->link('scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder'); but still nothing :/
My structure of folders is the same like it should be for lightbox (in webroot I have css, images and js folders).

Any ideas why it works like this?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Web Inspector in Safari or Chrome or the Firebug extension for Firefox.  Under the Network/Net tab, you can see all the files that are being loaded for your webpage.

From the small screenshot you included, it looks like the path to your image file is wrong.

Comment: I have checked that it see all my JavaScripts but path to the image is wrong hmmm I have to check it - Yes probably you are right! What a shame for me! Thank You veeerrryyy much!